# how to disable kite hint snippet setting in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, kite

The most recent update of Kite added a hint feature on the right of every line my cursor is on. [image: image1], [image: image2], which gets super annoying. I want to continue using Kite but I don't want this "Find related code in " to follow the cursor around.

Comment: I am curious, what intention of that constant decoration?

Answer (score 24):

For VSCode:
"Search in the settings for "Kite > Codefinder > Enable Line Decoration" and disable it. That helped me." (found on github)

For Atom:
"Settings > Packages > Kite > Enable codefinder decoration", disable this.

Answer (score 10):

For VSCode: go to settings.json and paste this line to your settings "kite.codefinder.enableLineDecoration": false

it worked for me and that annoying pop-up is gone.

Comment: After searching in settings, this popped up in my settings.json. Confirming both answers work.

Comment: glad I could help :)  
by the way, this was my first ever answer on stackoverflow.